# get list of all child class who have called a method from parent class

Tags: java

i have below scenario :

```
public class parent{
public void abc(){
 some logic ....
  }
}

public class child1 extends parent{
parent p1 = new parent();
 p1.abc();

}

public class child2 extends parent{
parent p1 = new parent();
 p1.abc();
}
```

from above scenario is it possible to know within parent class weather "child1" class has called method "abc()" of parent calls or  "child2" has called at run time

Please help

i ma new to java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 9 or above, you can use the [StackWalker API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html). It would be considerably cheaper than throwing and catching an exception to get access to the Stack Trace.

The the API reference:

> A stack walker.
>
> The walk method opens a sequential stream of StackFrames for the
>   current thread and then applies the given function to walk the
>   StackFrame stream. The stream reports stack frame elements in order,
>   from the top most frame that represents the execution point at which
>   the stack was generated to the bottom most frame. The StackFrame
>   stream is closed when the walk method returns. If an attempt is made
>   to reuse the closed stream, IllegalStateException will be thrown.
>
> The stack walking options of a StackWalker determines the information
>   of StackFrame objects to be returned. By default, stack frames of the
>   reflection API and implementation classes are hidden and StackFrames
>   have the class name and method name available but not the Class
>   reference.
>
> StackWalker is thread-safe. Multiple threads can share a single
>   StackWalker object to traverse its own stack. A permission check is
>   performed when a StackWalker is created, according to the options it
>   requests. No further permission check is done at stack walking time.

Parent:

```
public class Parent {
    public void abc() {
        final StackWalker walker = StackWalker.getInstance(Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
        Class<?> caller = walker.getCallerClass();
        System.out.println("Called from "+caller.getName());
    }
}
```

Child1:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    Parent p1 = new Parent();
    public void abc() {
        p1.abc();
    }
}
```

Child2:

```
public class Child2 extends Parent {
    Parent p1 = new Parent();
    public void abc() {
        p1.abc();
    }
}
```

Example output:

> ```
> Called from Child1
> Called from Child2
> ```

Note: Child1 and Child2 do not need to extend Parent to do this.  I assume you want to be able to do this without using inheritance, and I wanted to as close as possible to the code you have.

Comment: Regardless of whatever else you put, your first sentence is faulty. You don't need to catch an exception at all to use it. Sure it is more expensive to catch an exception. But all you need to do is `new Throwable()`, not catch.

Comment: @searchengine27 the *second* sentence isn't "faulty" because it doesn't mention other alternatives.  Perhaps it didn't cross your mind that they were deliberately left out.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need to instantiate parent class in child class object. However as you are `extending` parent class, all the child classes `child1` and `child2` already has the method `abc` (inheritance).

If you call methods using child class objects it is possible to get calling class name in parent class.

here is an example:

```
public class Parent {

    public void abc() {
        System.out.println(" Calling Class name:" + getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child1 child1 = new Child1();
        Child2 child2 = new Child2();
        WhatEverThatExtends haha = new WhatEverThatExtends();
        parent.abc();
        child1.abc();
        child2.abc();
        haha.abc();
    }
}


class Child1 extends Parent {
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
}

class WhatEverThatExtends extends Parent {
}
```

---

And the sample **output** is :

```
 Calling Class name:Parent
 Calling Class name:Child1
 Calling Class name:Child2
 Calling Class name:WhatEverThatExtends
```

---

If you always want to know the **calling class name**, either it extends or not, check out @Tibrogargan's answer.